# MATLAB calculate area of shape on plot

Tags: matlab, area

I Create a plot using imagesc. The X/Y axis are longitude and latitude respectively. The Z values are the intensity of the images for the image shown below. What I'd like to be able to do is calculate the area in each of the polygons shown. Can anybody recommend a straightforward (or any) method in accomplishing this?

**EDIT**

Forgot to include image.

[image]

Comment: Are the `Z` values outside the polygons a certain unique value, say 0? Or can a threshold be applied?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is a toy example. It hinges on the assumption that the `Z` values are different inside the objects from outside (here: not 0). Also here I assume a straight divider at column 4, but the same principle (applying a mask) can be applied with other boundaries. This also assumes that the values are equidistant along `x` and `y` axes, but the question does not state the opposite. If that is not the case, a little more work using `bsxfun` is needed.

```
A = [0     2     0     0     0     2     0
     3     5     3     0     1     4     0
     1     4     0     0     3     2     3
     2     3     0     0     0     4     2
     0     2     6     0     1     6     1
     0     3     0     0     2     3     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0];

area_per_pix = 0.5; % or whatever

% plot it 
cm = parula(10);
cm(1, :) = [1 1 1];
figure(1);
clf
imagesc(A);
colormap(cm);

% divider
dv_idx = 4;

left_object = A(:, 1:(dv_idx-1));
left_mask = left_object > 0; % threshold object
num_pix_left = sum(left_mask(:));

% right object, different method
right_mask = repmat((1:size(A, 2)) > dv_idx, size(A, 1), 1);
right_mask = (A > 0) & right_mask;
num_pix_right = sum(right_mask(:));

fprintf('The left object is %.2f units large, the right one %.2f units.\n', ...
    num_pix_left * area_per_pix, num_pix_right * area_per_pix);
```

Comment: It seems to meet the objective! However, I'm confused on some of the logic. How/why did you select area_per_pix? How/why did you select the div_idx? If we were to use the same method used originally on the left object, how would the A matrix be selected? Thanks.

Comment: @DeeTee `area_per_pix` is distance between two data points along x axis times the same along the y axis. I just picked an arbitrary value. It gets more complicated if not all data points have the same area. `div_idx` again was chosen to match my toy data. Here it is the column separating the two shapes. You'd have to get that from your data. If your data is not separable along one column, again there are other ways to define the mask.

Comment: @DeeTee not sure I understand the last question. The difference between the two approaches is that in the first one, we first pick the relevant part of `A` (which is easy, because we take everything up to a certain column), then threshold. This could be equal applied to the right one (using `(div_idx+1):end` as index). In the second approach, we threshold and combine this with a mask (which is a more general approach, as the mask could be arbitrary)

Comment: Copy all! Great solution!

Comment: Another question I thought about was if the area_per_pix was unknown or varied, couldn't we just apply the mask and sum it? That would give us the total sum of that particular object wouldn't it?

Comment: Sure, you could leave it out. Or you could create a matrix of the same size as `A`, and multiply it element-wise with the mask, then sum: as an example, `apix = bsxfun(@times, (1:size(A,1))' * .5, 1:size(A, 2)); weighted=right_mask.*apix; sum(weighted(:));` Here `apix` contains the area at each coordinate pair.

Comment: I noticed you are still multiplying by 0.5 in the bsxfun. What if we didn't know that value?

Comment: @DeeTee the hole idea of creating this `apix` matrix is that you know the relationship between your x/y coordinates and the size of that grid field. I just used 0.5 as an example, to scale differently along the dimensions. But in real life, `apix` would most likely look different, anyways. If you don't know dimensions, use the original approach and leave out `area_per_pix`.

Answer (score 0):

This might be helpful: http://se.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/35501-surface-area-from-a-z-matrix
He has not used imagesc, but it's a similar problem.

Comment: That problem is different in that the area to be integrated is a quadrilateral. Mine is more of a blob so I can't really cut it into triangles or other quadrilateral.